An orthonormal sequence of functions with sufficient pointwise cancellation
I suspect that someone immediately knows an answer to this question.
I am looking for an infinite sequence of real-valued continuous functions $f_j:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_1,f_2,\ldots,$ are an orthonormal set of functions in $L^2([0,1])$ with $\sum_{j=n}^\infty f_j(x)$ bounded for all $n$ and
$$
\frac{\|\sum_{j=n}^\infty f_j\|_\infty}{\|f_n\|_\infty}\rightarrow0,\qquad \text{as } n\rightarrow \infty.
$$
Here, $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the supremum norm on $[0,1]$. In essence, I want the sum $\sum_{j=n}^\infty f_j(x)$ to have lots of cancellation for all $n$.
Back story: I am trying to understand the convergence behavior of the singular value expansion for continuous non-symmetric bivariate functions. It turns out to be quite tricky. Part of this investigation requires me to build a sequence of right singular functions so that the singular value expansion is not uniformly convergent. I believe that an answer to the question above would help me understand the convergence of the singular value expansion for continuous non-symmetric functions.
